# Getting a list of Resource-Activities pairs. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

1. Here's a gist of **DbContext** and **models** I have in my project - [DbContextModels](https://gist.github.com/happygrizzly/ffe04d584aca4a037fa4).
2. These are the relationships:

   - **`User`**-**`Role`** as **M**:**M**
   - **`Role`**-**`Activity`**-**`Resource`** as **M**:**M**:**M**
3. Join table is defined explicitly as **`RoleResourceActivity`**
4. Consider the **Seed** method - [DbContextSeed](https://gist.github.com/happygrizzly/4bf2e4b0bee3ee1b23b1)

Below is the basic **sql** of what I'm trying to achieve with use of `Linq`-query:

```
select
    r.Name [resource], a.Name
from Activities a
    join RoleResourceActivities ra on ra.ActivityId = a.Id
    join Resources r on ra.ResourceId = r.Id
    join Roles ro on ra.RoleId = ro.Id
    join UserRoles ur on ur.Role_Id = ro.Id
    join Users u on ur.User_Id = u.Id
where u.Username = 'User'
group by r.Name, a.Name
```

The results for **User** and **User2** correspondingly:

[image]

**Question**

How to write such a `linq-query` so that the result set would consist of projected objects like:

```
new {
    Resource = Resource.Name,
    Activities = ListOfCorrespondingActivities
}
```

Or in **JSON**:

```
// Username: `User`, Roles: "SimpleUser", "AdvancedUser"
[
     {Resource: "blogs", Activities: ["Delete", "Read", "Update"]},
     {Resource: "talks", Activities: ["Delete", "Read", "Update"]}
]

// Username: `User2`, Roles: "SimpleUser"
[
     {Resource: "blogs", Activities: ["Read"]},
     {Resource: "talks", Activities: ["Read"]}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Resources and the related Activities from an User using this method:

```
public ILookup<string,string> GetResourcesAndActivitiesByUser(string userName)
{
        using (var _db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            return (from u in _db.Users
                    where u.UserName == userName
                    from a in _db.Activities
                    join ra in _db.RoleResourceActivities on a.Id equals ra.ActivityId
                    join r in _db.Resources on ra.ResourceId equals r.Id
                    join ro in _db.Roles on ra.RoleId equals ro.Id
                    where u.Roles.Contains(ro)
                    select new { Resource = r.Name, Activity = a.Name })
                    .ToLookup(e => e.Resource, e => e.Activity);
        }
}
```

If you want to create an `IEnumerable<>` based in the anonymous type as you show in your question, you can do this:

```
 var resources = GetResourcesAndActivitiesByUser("UserX").Select(e=>new {Resource=e.Key,Activities=e.ToList()});
```